# Difficulty Installing GLOBAL

Tags: package-management, emacs

Preface: I don't know what I am doing.

With that out of the way, I found a tutorial that is trying to make me a competent emacs user. In it, there was a section describing how to install GLOBAL. However, the guide gave me some commands that don't make sense/aren't working. I am assuming that the guide was made for someone who understands linux package installation and I don't. Anyways, here's the picture of the guide with the error messages.

[image]

The guide is one I found [here](http://tuhdo.github.io/emacs-tutor.html#orgheadline81).

Please help.

Comment: I decided that I don't care on account of I found it in the package manager.

Comment: Try `apt-get install libncurses5-dev` and then re-run the `./configure` step. You might get a different error before you will finally succeed. In that case please post the output as text, not as image.